# Ad-rotator-style image cycler in javascript, html

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I need some help with a javascript exercise for a course on internet programming. I'm still new to "the big 3," so there are some gaps in my understanding.

My task is to write a javascript code for an ad-rotator-style image slideshow. Once the page has loaded, it should display an image which cycles to a new image every 2 seconds. Eventually, I'd like to find a solution with no inline javascript, but for the sake of simplicity, I've condensed my javascript and HTML files into one.

**The code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <title>Image Cycle</title>
<script>
  function ImageCycle() {
    displaypic = document.GetElementById("displaypic");
    var i = 0;
    while (true) {
      switch(i){
        case 0:
          displaypic.src = "pic1.jpg";
          break;
        case 1:
          displaypic.src = "pic2.png";
          break;
        case 2: // falls thru to default
          displaypic.src = "pic3.jpg";
        default:
          i = -1; // reset iterator
        break;
      }
      setTimeout(function(){i++;}, 2000);
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="ImageCycle()">
  <div>
    <img id="displaypic" src="none" alt="3-picture slideshow"/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`pic1.jpg`, `pic2.png`, and `pic3.jpg` are all valid filenames and are located in the same directory as the HTML file.

**The issue:**
When I load the page in a browser, no images are displayed. When I did a bit of brute force-debugging, it seemed like ImageCycle wasn't being called at all, since additional statements in the function body didn't appear to execute.

**What I've tried:**

- moving script tag to all conceivable places within the HTML file
- linking the script from an external file
- different algorithms for ImageCycle
- moving the onload attribute to other tags, before after, and within the img tag
- using other HTML attributes to call ImageCycle

**What I need to know:**

- How do I use HTML to call a javascript function that should always run in the background?
- What is the best way to write this algorithm in javascript?
- Why did my approach fail?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a recursive function (ie one that calls itself) instead of a while loop. Then in your setTimeout you will want to call the function from within itself.

Instead of using a switch, I chose an array simply because it's cleaner, easier to use and easier to add more to.

setTimeout will run the code within the callback area. In your code, you were just incrementing i, but at no time reusing that i update anywhere. While true kept running but it never gets the updated `i` counter.

```js
var i = 0;
displaypic = document.getElementById("displaypic");

images = ["https://via.placeholder.com/333/333/aa00ff", "https://via.placeholder.com/333/333/00aaff", "https://via.placeholder.com/333/333/00ffaa"];

function ImageCycle() {
  displaypic.src = images[i];
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (i == images.length - 1) {
      i = 1;
    } else {
      i++;
    }
    ImageCycle()
  }, 2000);
}

ImageCycle()
```

```html
<img id="displaypic" src="none" alt="3-picture slideshow" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm quite familiar with recursion, but a little confused about how it works in javascript. Wouldn't your proposed solution eventually eat up all available memory since the function never returns? Also, how do you recommend invoking this javascript function in an HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

Arrived at a solution. Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>Image Cycle</title>
      <!-- <script src = "RandomPicture.js"></script> -->
      <script>
        var displaypic;
        var pictures = [ "pic1", "pic2", "pic3"];
        var descriptions = [ "picture 1", "picture 2", "picture 3" ];
        var index = 0;

        function pickImage() {
           index = (index + 1) % pictures.length;
           displaypic.setAttribute( "src", pictures[ index ] + ".jpg" );
           displaypic.setAttribute( "alt", descriptions[ index ] );
        }

        function start() {
           displaypic = document.getElementById( "displaypic" );
           setInterval(function(){pickImage()},1000);
        } // end function start

        window.addEventListener('load', start);
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <img id="displaypic" src="pic1.jpg" alt="picture 1"></img>
   </body>
</html>
```

The key pieces I was missing in my original attempt:

- use of the window.AddEventListener('load', start) call to start
  script running as soon as the page loads.
- use of the setInterval function rather than setTimeout to get a given
  script to run periodically
- breaking the script up into two functions, start and pickImage; start
  runs continuously, calling pickImage every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation of HTML pages are top-down.
Many programmers put their script in the final part of the body.
this way there is no need to use a page load event.

My slider point of view :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <title>Image Cycle</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="display-pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/264/500/300.jpg" alt="picture 1"></img>

<script>
  const timeDelay  = 2000  // ==2s
    ,   displayPic = document.getElementById('display-pic')
    ,   pics =
          [ { src: '264/500/300' , desc: 'picture 1' } 
          , { src: '268/500/300' , desc: 'picture 2' }
          , { src: '273/500/300' , desc: 'picture 3' }
          ]
    ;
  var index      = 0
    , timeTarget = new Date().getTime() +timeDelay
    ;
  setInterval(()=>
    {
    let now = new Date().getTime()
    if (now >= timeTarget)
      {
      index = ++index % pics.length
      displayPic.src = `https://picsum.photos/id/${pics[index].src}.jpg`
      displayPic.alt = pics[index].desc
      }
    },250);
  displayPic.onload=()=>
    {
    timeTarget = new Date().getTime() +timeDelay
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

With this method, even heavy to loaded images will be able to respect the display time. as an option you can also add an external control to vary the duration without interrupting the slidder

sample code:

```js
const btPlayPause  = document.getElementById('bt-play-pause')
  ,   displayDelay = document.getElementById('display-delay')
  ,   displayPic   = document.getElementById('display-pic')
  ,   pics =
        [ { src: '251', desc: 'picture 1' } 
        , { src: '252', desc: 'picture 2' }
        , { src: '253', desc: 'picture 3' }
        , { src: '254', desc: 'picture 4' }
        , { src: '255', desc: 'picture 5' }
        , { src: '256', desc: 'picture 6' }
        ]
  ;
displayDelay.value = 2  // init value
var timeDelay  = 2000  // ==2s
  , index      = 0
  , timeStart  = new Date().getTime()
  , timeTarget = timeStart + timeDelay
  , imgLoaded  = false
  , imgTimer   = 0
  ;
function startTimerParms()
  {
  timeStart  = new Date().getTime()
  timeTarget = timeStart + timeDelay
  imgLoaded  = true
  }
displayPic.onload = startTimerParms
  ;
btPlayPause.onclick=()=>
  {
  let noPlay = (btPlayPause.textContent !== 'Play')
  btPlayPause.textContent = noPlay ? 'Play' : 'Stop'
    ;
  if ( noPlay )
    {
    clearInterval(imgTimer)
    }
  else
    {
    startTimerParms()
    timeTarget = 0  // for immediate changing on Play button
      ;
    imgTimer = setInterval(()=> {
      let now = new Date().getTime()
      if (imgLoaded && now >= timeTarget)
        {
        imgLoaded      = false
        index          = ++index % pics.length
        displayPic.alt = pics[index].desc
        displayPic.src = `https://picsum.photos/id/${pics[index].src}/500/300.jpg`
        }
      },100)}
  }
displayDelay.oninput=()=>
  {
  displayDelay.nextElementSibling.textContent = displayDelay.value +'"' 
  timeDelay  = displayDelay.valueAsNumber *1000
  timeTarget = timeStart + timeDelay
  }
```

```html
<button id="bt-play-pause">Play</button>  
Delay : <input id="display-delay" type="range" value="2" min="1" max="10" step="0.2"><span>2"</span><br><br>
<img id="display-pic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/251/500/300.jpg" alt="picture 1"></img>
```